# Use mybatis-plus to manipulate java record class and report error for insert operation

Tags: java, mysql, record, mybatis-plus

I hava a record class as java bean:

```java
@With
@TableName(value = "user")
public record User(
        @TableId(value = "uid", type = IdType.AUTO)
        Integer id,
        String username,
        String password,
) {}
```

then I use mybatis-plus to manage it:

```java
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserMapper userMapper;
    public UserServiceImpl(UserMapper userMapper) {
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public CommonResponse<Object> register(User user) {

        String password = "9ABB136AA0B984E8";
        User newUser = user.withPassword(password)

        int rows = userMapper.insert(newUser);  // got a MyBatisSystemException
        if (rows == 0) {
            return CommonResponse.createResponseForError();
        }
        return CommonResponse.createResponseForSuccess();
    }
}
```

The UserMapper is the default implementation of mybatis-plus

```java
public interface UserMapper extends BaseMapper<User> {}
```

When I execute the INSERT operation on it, the code reports an error:

```
Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: No setter found for the keyProperty 'id' in 'com.csu.mypetstore.api.domain.User'.
```

I know that the cause of this error is that the record class cannot perform setter operations, but I don't know how to get around this error and implement self-incrementing operations on the database.

I have tried adding the setId method to the User record class, but it doesn't work.

```java
@With
@TableName(value = "user")
public record User(
        @TableId(value = "uid", type = IdType.AUTO)
        Integer id,
        String username,
        String password,
) {
        public User setId(Integer id){
                return new User(id, username, password);  // No use
        }
}
```

What can I do to accomplish mybatis-plus operations on the record class, such as completing an insert operation on a table with a self-incrementing primary key, or does the record class not apply to mybatis-plus?